# Having trouble with awaitReactions

Tags: discord, discord.js

I want to make a confessions bot where it sends the confession to a private group so it can be reviwed before it is sent to the public channel. But I can't figure out a way to use awaitReactions.

```js
const discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: 'confessions',
    description: "comando para as pessoas confessarem anonimamente",
    
    execute(message, args) {
        let cf = args.join(' ')
        message.delete()
        const cfAdm = message.guild.channels.cache.get('767082831205367809')
        let embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('**CONFISSÃO**')
            .setDescription(cf)
            .setColor('#000000')
        cfAdm.send(embed)
            .then(function (message) {
                message.react('').then(() => message.react(''));
            });
    }
}
```

the idea is: someone sends a confession, the bot deletes it and sends it to a channel that only admins can see. then any one of the admins can accept or deny it by reacting to thumbs up or down. if the confession is accepted, then it goes to the public confessions channel, and if it isn't the person should receive a private message saying their confession was dennied.

if anyone has some idea on how to make awaitReactions work in this way(or if you have a better idea), it would be greatly apreciated.

thank you in advance and sorry for any bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation

#### Arguments

[awaitReactions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=awaitReactions) takes `filter` and `options` as arguments.

`filter` is a function to determine whether a `reaction` done by `user` needs to be collected.
For example, you want to collect only  or  and ignore other react such as . Therefore, your filter may be like this:

```js
const filter = (reaction, user) => ['', ''].includes(reaction.emoji.name);
```

`options` is the option to determine when to stop collecting reacts.
There are [3 configurable parameters](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ReactionCollectorOptions):

- `max`: The maximum total amount of reactions to collect
- `maxEmojis`: The maximum number of emojis to collect
- `maxUsers`: The maximum number of users to react

In your case, you only want to collect one (valid) emoji to determine whether the post should be posted to the public channel. Therefore, you may want to set your `options` to:

```js
const options = {
  maxEmojis: 1, // stop collecting if any 1 valid emoji is collected
}
```

#### Return Value

`awaitReactions` returns a Promise, which is resolved when the collection finishes, and return a `Collection` of the collected reactions.
In your case, because you only care about the first reaction, you only need to check the first reaction in the collection `collected.first()`, and determine whether to send the message to the public channel or not. Therefore, the handler will be like:

```js
collected => {
  if (collected.first().emoji.name === '') {
    // send the message to the public channel
  }
}
```

### Conclusion

Combining above, you can use `awaitReactions` like this:

```js
execute(message, args) {
  let cf = args.join(' ')
  message.delete()
  const cfAdm = message.guild.channels.cache.get('767082831205367809')
  let embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('**CONFISSÃO**')
    .setDescription(cf)
    .setColor('#000000')

  const filter = (reaction, user) => ['', ''].includes(reaction.emoji.name);
  const reactOptions = {maxEmojis: 1};
  
  cfAdm.send(embed)
  .then(function (message) {
    message.react('')
    .then(() => message.react(''))
    /**** start collecting reacts ****/
    .then(() => message.awaitReactions(filter, reactOptions))
    /**** collection finished! ****/
    .then(collected => {
      if (collected.first().emoji.name === '') {
        // send the message to the public channel
      }
    })
  });
}
```

Or you can use async/await to simplify the code:

```js
async execute(message, args) {
  let cf = args.join(' ')
  message.delete()
  const cfAdm = message.guild.channels.cache.get('767082831205367809')
  let embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('**CONFISSÃO**')
    .setDescription(cf)
    .setColor('#000000')

  const filter = (reaction, user) => ['', ''].includes(reaction.emoji.name);
  const reactOptions = {maxEmojis: 1};
  
  const messageReact = await cfAdm.send(embed);
  await messageReact.react('');
  await messageReact.react('');
  /**** collect reacts ****/
  const collected = await messageReact.awaitReactions(filter, reactOptions);
  /**** determine whether to post message or not ****/
  if (collected.first().emoji.name === '') {
    // send `message` to the public channel
  }
}
```

Hope this is clear enough to understand :)

Comment: Mate, not only did you help me, but you also thought me somenthing. I can't thank you enough

Comment: So glad to hear that! I recommend to read the official documents, try the examples, and try to guess what the examples are trying to do. It may be difficult at the beginning, but after some experience, it will be very useful. (In fact, I didn't know anything about `awaitReactions` before trying to answer to your question!) Hope your development goes smoothly :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure if this little snippet off of mine code will help you, but I hope it does. There is way better ways of doing this too but I like doing it the hard way..

```js
const { promptMessage } = require("../../functions.js");
await message.channel.send(embed).then(async msg => {
    const emoji = await promptMessage(msg, message.author, 30, ["✅", "❌"]);
        // Check, if emoji ->
            if (emoji === "✅") {
                //do stuff
  }}
```

This means with my example you would also need to create that `functions.js` file, which would be

```js
module.exports = {
    getMember: function(message, toFind = '') {
        toFind = toFind.toLowerCase();

        let target = message.guild.members.get(toFind);
        
        if (!target && message.mentions.members)
            target = message.mentions.members.first();

        if (!target && toFind) {
            target = message.guild.members.find(member => {
                return member.displayName.toLowerCase().includes(toFind) ||
                member.user.tag.toLowerCase().includes(toFind)
            });
        }
            
        if (!target) 
            target = message.member;
            
        return target;
    },

    formatDate: function(date) {
        return new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(date)
    },

    promptMessage: async function (message, author, time, validReactions) {
        // We put in the time as seconds, with this it's being transfered to MS
        time *= 1000;

        // For every emoji in the function parameters, react in the good order.
        for (const reaction of validReactions) await message.react(reaction);

        // Only allow reactions from the author, 
        // and the emoji must be in the array we provided.
        const filter = (reaction, user) => validReactions.includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === author.id;

        // And ofcourse, await the reactions
        return message
            .awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: time})
            .then(collected => collected.first() && collected.first().emoji.name);
    }
};
```