# How to fix timeout error when using awaitReactions() function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

I have written this code in my Bot and it doesn't work properly. The function `awaitReactions()` is always timing out:

```js
message.channel.send({ embed: hEmbed }).then(embedreacted => {
        embedreacted.react('').then(() => embedreacted.react(''));

        const filter = (reaction, user) => {
            console.log("user \n" + user)
            return ['', ''].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
        };

        embedreacted.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 20000, errors: ['time'] })
            .then(collected => {
                console.log("col" + collected)
                const reaction = collected.first();
                if (reaction.emoji.name == '') {
                    let hlembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                        Embed
                    embedreacted.edit({ embed: hlembed });
                } else if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
                    let hfEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                     Embed
                    embedreacted.edit({ embed: hfEmbed });
                }
                for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(reaction)) {
                    console.log(key, value);
                }

            })
            .catch(collected => {
                console.log("collected \n" + collected.keys())
            });
```

Comment: @Toasty - Have you any Idea why this isnt working?

Comment: Do you want to listen for reactions on this message forever or just the 20 seconds?

Comment: @Toasty - Only for the 20 Seconds but the awaitReactions Function doesnt give a Result

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64409108/13685706) can fix your problem

Comment: @Toasty - It works a little bit now he does what he should do but he does it too when the bot himself reacts on it and I only want, that the Bot only do something when the message author reacts but when I try to add "&& user.id === message.author.id" it doesnt work anymore.

Comment: Just put `if(user.bot) return` before your code

Comment: @Toasty - It doesnt help either when I add this he does nothing anymore and If i put it before the awaitReaction he send only the Message and Reactions but he dont get the Reactions

Comment: Put that line right under the `<client>.on(...)` line

Answer (score 0):

In your `filter` function:

```js
const filter = (reaction, user) => {
    console.log("user \n" + user)
    return ['', ''].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
};
```

`message.author.id` is the bot's user ID, because the message to which the reactions are being "awaited" was created by the bot. So the condition `user.id === message.author.id` will only trigger when the bot's user reacts to it.

I'm not sure if this is what you want but if you want it to only trigger when a user reacts to it (and not the bot itself) just do `user.id !== <Client>.user.id` or even `user.id !== message.author.id` as a shortcut.

If you wish to receive a reaction only from the user that created a prior message to this one, you need to set that `<Message>` object to a variable and then use `user.id === variable.author.id`